# Legacy torchtext 0.9.0

Tags: pytorch, torchtext

In the latest release of torchtext they moved a lot of features to `torchtext.legacy`, I want to do the same things like `torchtext.legacy.data.Field` and other features without using `legacy`, is that can be done? and how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### EDIT:

- [here](https://github.com/pytorch/text/releases/tag/v0.9.0-rc5) is a release note about `0.9.0` version
- [here](https://github.com/pytorch/text/blob/master/examples/legacy_tutorial/migration_tutorial.ipynb) is the migration guide

Also, in the first link, there are counterparts for legacy Datasets.

### Old answer (might be useful)

You could go for an alias, namely:

```
import torchtext.legacy as torchtext
```

But this is a bad idea for multiple reasons:

- It became legacy for a reason (you can always change your existing code to `torchtext.legacy.data.Field`)
- **Very confusing** - `torchtext` should `torchtext`, not `torchtext.legacy`
- **Unable to import `torchtext` as... `torchtext`** - because this alias is already taken.

You could also do some workarounds like assigning `torch.legacy.data.Field` to `torch.data.Field` and what not, but it is a horrible idea.

**If you want to work with this `legacy` stuff, you can always stay with smaller version of `torchtext` like `0.8.0` and this would make sense**

Comment: The main point is i don't want to work with legacy anymore, i want to work with the new feature that replaces `Field`

Comment: @KickItLikeShika edited, in the second link there is a tutorial, where `Field` is replaced using new approach.